# Maven build on save

Tags: eclipse, maven, build

I just jumped into a webapplication that uses Maven. It's a project that's been around for some months now and a lot have people worked on it and left. So it's a mess and there hasn't been a lot of documenting around it.

So I've been trying to find my way around the project and something I've been running into is that I have to build 2 folders, move a file into the server folder to see the changes I've made. This is a slow and tedious process, so I'm trying to speed it up.

We are all using the Eclipse IDE and after I've done changes in the code I have to right click a the rootfolder > run as > maven build > goals: clean install. This I have to do for two folders.

Then I have to close Wildfly (the server app for the project) and move a .ear file from folder a to b and restard Wildfly to see my changes. As you can see this takes quite some actions so I'm looking for a method to automate this.

Is it possible to configure this in Eclipse or should I look into creating a .bat file that a user can run that performs the actions stated above?

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse by default should build each class file as you edit it.

I would suggest running Wildfly within Eclipse.  Take a look at JBoss tools for some better integration in this area. Once you have it configured to run within Eclipse then it should auto reload the files as you edit them - no need to even restart Wildfly.

Comment: So I don't have to do the maven rebuild to get the changes in the Wildfly server? That sounds great.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a batch file:

```
rem run a maven clean install
cd C:\Users\A647450\workspace\****\*****
call mvn clean install
rem run a maven clean install
cd C:\Users\A647450\workspace\*****\****
call mvn clean install
rem copy created EAR file to Wildfly folder
copy C:\Users\A647450\workspace\****\****\target\****-1.2.1-SNAPSHOT.ear C:\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\standalone\deployments\****-1.2.1-SNAPSHOT.ear /y
```

This does get the job done, but takes a while.